# Lottie Animation Dynamic Text Animation

Tags: android, lottie

I need to set text for a LottieAnimationView, but the documentation isn't helping me much

[image]

I tried adding a text view on the layout, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
 android:background="@color/trans_100"
 android:id="@+id/animation_view"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="center"/>

 <TextView
   android:id="@+id/title"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/text_value"
   android:textSize="20sp"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   />
```

Comment: please add a code of what you tried and didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can put a text in the animation because is like an image (you don't have the source for edit this).

However, if you use relative or constraintlayout you can do the trick by using:

In relative layout:

```
<TextView
   android:paddingTop="-10dp"
   android:id="@+id/title"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/text_value"
   android:textSize="20sp"
   android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

In constraintlayout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:background="@color/trans_100"
            android:id="@+id/animation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_value"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@null"
            app:textAllCaps="false" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Right now i am doing a test with the information a gave you with a Lottie Animation I am working in `ConstraintLayout` a this is the result:

[image: result]